# Change macro location of a custom button in ribbon

Tags: excel, vba

It is possible to change the "location" of the macro that runs when clicking on a custom button that was added to the ribbon?

Let me explain the situation:

I'm starting from a template (let's say template.xltm, so my temporary file is template01) , which contains that ribbon code.

I save that template-sheet into the file I want, let's say file1.xlsm.
Now I want to click that button again in the ribbon, the code should be run from the file1.xlsm macro (that has the same function name) and not from that template file (template.xltm).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the macro to the ribbon should be enough as the macro will run on the file it was activated from rather then the file it is stored in.

I have a whole bunch of different macros that I use regularly and needed quick and simple way to access it so I designated a workbook for my macros and created a custom tab with buttons for all macros I need.

Comment: Hmm here it's not working this way...
I have a sub in that template file called (let's say) "MacroTest". 
In my ribbon I have added that button that links to this sub (so template.xltm > MacroTest).
Now that I'm in the file1.xlsm (which was saved from my template) and I click that button, the button will run the function 'MacroTest' from the template.xltm instead of the 'MacroTest' from the current file (in my example file1.xlsm).
Yours is not acting like this ?

Comment: You are right, it will go back to the macro from the template file because the shortcut button is linked to the macro in the template file. Did you edit the macro from the "file1.xlsm" that you specifically need access to the one stored there? I have a workbook designated to storing my macros and most of my excel files are saved as a simple .xlsx even though I use macros in almost all of them.

Comment: If you specifically need it should run the macro from "file1" you would need to insert a button into the excel sheet directly as the extension to the macro gets saved when you save it on the ribbon.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes the function needs to be run from the file, and not from the template, because it uses data from the file. But I'm thinking, can you change the code this way it takes the values from the current file? If yes it doesn't matter if the code is run from the template or the current file. If it's not possible I guess I will have to add a button on the file itself instead of a button on the ribbon.

Comment: The macro will use the data of the workbook from which it was activated. Unless it is specifically coded to look elsewhere. If for example you have a sheet titled "apples" in both your template and in "file1", when the program says to do something in the "apples" sheet it will make the changes in "file1" because that is where you ran the code from. If you would want to change something in the template file by clicking on the button from "file1" you would first have to tell vba to activate the template...